# Should I separate Spring Security from Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

I'm working on a Spring Boot Application which has both REST API and `JWT` Authentication. But It's over-weighted and I'm planning to detach the Security module to another `micro-service.`

What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of having this level of separation?

Are there any security concerns that may introduce vulnerabilities in the separated REST API?

Answer (score 2):

You can do authentication on a different service or even use a thirdparty tool or provider e.g. Auth0 or Keycloak. 
Only the authorization should be in the "business" service.