# Import and use a spring security project in a spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-security

I'm a beginner in Spring Framework.
I created in two separate projects:

- Project "A" for Spring Security and JWT with a DB for User, Permission, Role, etc. Used for authentication and permissions;
- Project "B" for Spring Boot with a DB for business tables. Used as a backend for a web-app;

Both projects have controllers and starters (do not import).

I would like to know how to use authentication check ( JWTFilter ) and permissions ( PermissionEvaluator ) from the security project in the backend project.
In the future, I want to use same spring security project for multiple spring boot projects.

If necessary, I can add the basic structure (packages) of each project.

**AGGIORNAMENTO**

After so much research, [Should I separate Spring Security from Spring Boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60575209/10871634) and [Spring Boot configure and use two data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30337582/10871634) threads were very helpful in solving my problem.

However, in my case I didn't need to diversify the dataSource because the DB is unique but with a different schema for the business and security tables.
Then, I added the "schema" key to the spring @Table annotation. Also, to solve the problem for visibility of the repositories and entities I added the spring annotations @ComponentScan, @EnableJpaRepository and @EntityScan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two approaches to implement your project:

1. Deploy all packages of project B in the project A. this approach appropriate for small project.
2. Similar the approach 1 use the multi module architecture that is a clean way to implement. but in this approach you must set basic package in all of the modules

Comment: Why in approach 1 I have to import project B to A and not A to B ? The second approach is what I currently use. however, consider that each project has its own properties file and is associated with a specific DB schema.

Comment: No any difference. you can add project A To B. But usually Spring Security contain a lot of implementation and settings. as a result it is reasonable smaller project add to larger project.

Comment: Ok, but I have a problem: both spring projects use a properties file and are connected to different DB. I don't know how to import project A into B or vice versa and each project can access its DB. Also, I consider that both webservices are started.